# z-index image not showing when used next prev button like image gallery using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".divs div.panel").each(function(e) { 
              if (e > 2) 
                  $(this).hide(); 
                  console.log(e); 
          }); 
         
          $("#next").click(function(){ 
              if ($(".divs div.panel:visible:last").next().length != 0){ 
                  $(".divs div.panel:visible:last").next().show(); 
                  $(".divs div.panel:visible:last").next().show(); 
                  $(".divs div.panel:visible:first").hide(); 
                  $(".divs div.panel:visible:first").hide(); 
              } 
              else { 
                  //either hide the next button or show 1st two again. :) 
              } 
              return false; 
          }); 
         
          $("#prev").click(function(){ 
              if ($(".divs div.panel:visible:first").prev().length != 0){ 
                  var curVisLen = $(".divs div.panel:visible").length; 
                 $(".divs div.panel:visible:first").prev().show(); 
                  $(".divs div.panel:visible:first").prev().show(); 
                  $(".divs div.panel:visible:last").hide(); 
                  if(curVisLen == 3){ 
                    $(".divs div.panel:visible:last").hide(); 
                  } 
              } 
              else { 
                  // either hide the button or show last two divs 
                  // $(".divs div.panel:visible").hide(); 
                  // $(".divs div.panel:last").show(); 
              } 
              return false; 
          }); 
          });
```

```css
body{
  background-color: grey;
}
  .dash-img-dv{
  position: absolute;
  width: 170px;
  height: 221px;
   -moz-box-shadow: inset 5px -59px 63px 4px #5642BE;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 5px -59px 63px 4px #5642BE;
    box-shadow: inset 5px -59px 63px 4px #5642BE;
  }
  .dash-img-dv img { 
  width: 170px;
  height: 221px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: -1;
}
.dash-img-dv-ttle{
  position: relative;
  width: 153px;
  height: 50px;
  color: #fff;
  margin-left: 16px;
  margin-top: 167px;
  z-index: 1;
}
.panel{
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
.gallery {
  background: #CCC;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-top: 22px;
}
.prev-next-button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #5642BE;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
.prev-next-button a{
  color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  left: 28%;
  top: 21%;
}
.previous { left: -16px; }
.next { right: -16px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="gallery">
<div class="divs">

    <div class="panel">
      <div class="dash-img-dv">
        <img src="http://www.istockphoto.com/resources/images/PhotoFTLP/img_63351521.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="dash-img-dv-ttle">
        <p>This is title1</p>
      </div> 
    </div>
    <div class="panel">
      <div class="dash-img-dv">
        <img src="http://www.istockphoto.com/resources/images/PhotoFTLP/img_63351521.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="dash-img-dv-ttle">
        <p>This is title2</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel">
      <div class="dash-img-dv">
        <img src="http://www.istockphoto.com/resources/images/PhotoFTLP/img_63351521.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="dash-img-dv-ttle">
        <p>This is title3</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel">
      <div class="dash-img-dv">
        <img src="http://www.istockphoto.com/resources/images/PhotoFTLP/img_63351521.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="dash-img-dv-ttle">
        <p>This is title4</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel">
      <div class="dash-img-dv">
        <img src="http://www.istockphoto.com/resources/images/PhotoFTLP/img_63351521.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="dash-img-dv-ttle">
        <p>This is title5</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel">
      <div class="dash-img-dv">
        <img src="http://www.istockphoto.com/resources/images/PhotoFTLP/img_63351521.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="dash-img-dv-ttle">
        <p>This is title6</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel">
      <div class="dash-img-dv">
        <img src="http://www.istockphoto.com/resources/images/PhotoFTLP/img_63351521.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="dash-img-dv-ttle">
        <p>This is title7</p>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!--  <a id="prev">prev</a>
<a id="next">next</a> -->
<div class="prev-next-button previous">
   <a id="prev"><span class="fa fa-chevron-left"></span></a>
</div>
 <div class="prev-next-button next">
     <a id="next"><span class="fa fa-chevron-right"></span></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

I want to show my next previous div with images using jquery. I tried something like bellow.Everything is almost fine but problem is now that the images is not showing. Is there any z-index problem or something like that? I could not find the reason why images are not showing. Would anyone please help me to show the images?Here is the image bellow before write the script
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The negative `z-index` on the image will push it behind everything else on the page that isn't positioned. Add a `z-index` to `.panel` so that the negative `z-index` on the image doesn't push it behind `.panel` and keeps it between `.panel` and the element with the inner box shadow you want it to appear below.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".divs div.panel").each(function(e) { 
              if (e > 2) 
                  $(this).hide(); 
                  console.log(e); 
          }); 
         
          $("#next").click(function(){ 
              if ($(".divs div.panel:visible:last").next().length != 0){ 
                  $(".divs div.panel:visible:last").next().show(); 
                  $(".divs div.panel:visible:last").next().show(); 
                  $(".divs div.panel:visible:first").hide(); 
                  $(".divs div.panel:visible:first").hide(); 
              } 
              else { 
                  //either hide the next button or show 1st two again. :) 
              } 
              return false; 
          }); 
         
          $("#prev").click(function(){ 
              if ($(".divs div.panel:visible:first").prev().length != 0){ 
                  var curVisLen = $(".divs div.panel:visible").length; 
                 $(".divs div.panel:visible:first").prev().show(); 
                  $(".divs div.panel:visible:first").prev().show(); 
                  $(".divs div.panel:visible:last").hide(); 
                  if(curVisLen == 3){ 
                    $(".divs div.panel:visible:last").hide(); 
                  } 
              } 
              else { 
                  // either hide the button or show last two divs 
                  // $(".divs div.panel:visible").hide(); 
                  // $(".divs div.panel:last").show(); 
              } 
              return false; 
          }); 
          });
```

```css
body{
  background-color: grey;
}
  .dash-img-dv{
  position: absolute;
  width: 170px;
  height: 221px;
   -moz-box-shadow: inset 5px -59px 63px 4px #5642BE;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 5px -59px 63px 4px #5642BE;
    box-shadow: inset 5px -59px 63px 4px #5642BE;
  }
  .dash-img-dv img { 
  width: 170px;
  height: 221px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: -1;
}
.dash-img-dv-ttle{
  position: relative;
  width: 153px;
  height: 50px;
  color: #fff;
  margin-left: 16px;
  margin-top: 167px;
  z-index: 1;
}
.panel{
  display: inline-block;
  margin-left: 10px;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}
.gallery {
  background: #CCC;
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding-top: 22px;
}
.prev-next-button {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  width: 30px;
  height: 30px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: #5642BE;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}
.prev-next-button a{
  color: #fff;
  position: absolute;
  left: 28%;
  top: 21%;
}
.previous { left: -16px; }
.next { right: -16px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="gallery">
<div class="divs">

    <div class="panel">
      <div class="dash-img-dv">
        <img src="http://www.istockphoto.com/resources/images/PhotoFTLP/img_63351521.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="dash-img-dv-ttle">
        <p>This is title1</p>
      </div> 
    </div>
    <div class="panel">
      <div class="dash-img-dv">
        <img src="http://www.istockphoto.com/resources/images/PhotoFTLP/img_63351521.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="dash-img-dv-ttle">
        <p>This is title2</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel">
      <div class="dash-img-dv">
        <img src="http://www.istockphoto.com/resources/images/PhotoFTLP/img_63351521.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="dash-img-dv-ttle">
        <p>This is title3</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel">
      <div class="dash-img-dv">
        <img src="http://www.istockphoto.com/resources/images/PhotoFTLP/img_63351521.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="dash-img-dv-ttle">
        <p>This is title4</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel">
      <div class="dash-img-dv">
        <img src="http://www.istockphoto.com/resources/images/PhotoFTLP/img_63351521.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="dash-img-dv-ttle">
        <p>This is title5</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel">
      <div class="dash-img-dv">
        <img src="http://www.istockphoto.com/resources/images/PhotoFTLP/img_63351521.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="dash-img-dv-ttle">
        <p>This is title6</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="panel">
      <div class="dash-img-dv">
        <img src="http://www.istockphoto.com/resources/images/PhotoFTLP/img_63351521.jpg">
      </div>
      <div class="dash-img-dv-ttle">
        <p>This is title7</p>
      </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!--  <a id="prev">prev</a>
<a id="next">next</a> -->
<div class="prev-next-button previous">
   <a id="prev"><span class="fa fa-chevron-left"></span></a>
</div>
 <div class="prev-next-button next">
     <a id="next"><span class="fa fa-chevron-right"></span></a>
  </div>
</div>
```